# Road to becoming a professional software developer

Tags: software-industry, job-search, career-development, careers

**Background**

I am 25-year old hobbyist programmer who loves the thrill of abstraction that comes with spending long hours trying to fit all the concept pieces together to create a working program with great hopes that others find it useful. I am also quite passionate about open-source development and collaborating with like-minded individuals. This involves setting up project guidelines, workflow pipeline and organization tools as well as documenting both the code and my intentions behind the implementation.

I have a long history of coding in multiple languages but mostly prefer Java these days in which I have a couple of years worth of experience. I am **without any formal education** in software development or anything relating to that field of expertise. Starting this winter I plan on getting serious about my steady on and off relationship with my mistress, the queen of pragmatism who speaks only in *zeroes and ones* by learning Java from ground up getting a strong grasp on basic and more advanced concepts of the language itself as well as the ins and outs of object-oriented programming in general. To prove my intentions to her I have made a commitment of daily contributions on StackOverflow.

Due to economic reasons I am currently living in a foreign country *(which language I do not speak)* working as a street musician after a long backpacking journey across Europe. As much as I love the freedom that my lifestyle brings it is not without faults, but I don't want to bore you with my stories any more then I already have so I will get straight to the point.

**Question**

Taking all that I've said *(including my current situation)* into account and assuming I have educated myself in terms of coding to a level one would normally achieve after just finishing college what would be the best **objective** way to go about finding a job in the field of software development?

Read **additional information** section for specific details on what options I am considering and what I would be willing to do as well as the **follow-up question** section for more specific questions.

If you were in a situation even somewhat similar to mine please share your story and provide details on "what" and "why" affected the outcome of your quest and where you are now. If possible also provide useful references that you think might be helpful to me and others in this situation.

Help me turn my dreams into reality and thank you in advance!

**Follow-up questions**

- Due to a strong language barrier finding local job opportunities would prove to be quite difficult so my current thinking is that remote jobs would be better suited for me, although I am aware they are more difficult to come by. How would I go about researching my options in the area of remote work?
- I am active on Github and I try to post all of my code there which can be used as a resume of sort. What is the best way of building a portfolio that would be appealing to employers?
- I am willing to get one or more formal degrees or any type of certificate in fields that would prove useful to acquiring a job. Can you list types of degrees that have been proven to be particularly useful for someone in my situation?

**Additional information**

- The type of job is not a concern to me as long as my duties would primarily revolve around either designing, writing, testing or documenting code in a programming language I feel proficient in.
- The question is specific to software development so please let me know if you don't think it belongs on this site and point me in the direction where it would be appropriate to ask such a question.

Comment: I've tried to make the question *on-topic* and not seem like it's asking for **advice on a specific** choice by providing follow-up questions that are asking for *specific details*. Please tell me what more in particular I should change to make my question better. Thank you.

Comment: "Road to becoming a professional software developer"  the best way is to actually develop something that you can show potential employers. A big plus if they can interact with it too.

Comment: Don't waste your time with academia. Get straight into looking for a developer job. You'll have an income, gather actual job experience as an employee, and you can start your career and advance. You may have to start with a lower wage, but you'd save 3+ years of academia and a lot of debt, only to get an optional certificate and barely useful knowledge, after which your wage will be higher than that of an academic starters. Prove your skills by expanding on the projects you worked on and their difficulties. Once you are in, getting new employment becomes easier.

Comment: @Jonast92 In terms of what it can do, are there specific demo applications that are more attractive then others to potential employers?

Comment: I cannot agree more with @Jonast92 , lately I participated in the process to hire 3 persons and the few candidates that had something to show on their github account were automatically contacted.

Comment: @Battle Thank you for your response. I've heard that from multiple people already working in the industry. Can you tell me how in particular should go about looking for a job? I know this sounds silly but I have to be honest and say that I don't have any experience with looking for a job and was hoping you guys can help me out. Do you have an references to material I can read to better prepare myself for starting the search.

Comment: @Matthew I suggest to create something on a topic that you like with the stack that you found on jobs posted locally.

Comment: @SebastienDErrico that's good to hear. I am trying to commit everything I am working on Github, but for now it's just game related stuff that wouldn't be interesting to any serious employer. Do you have any particular suggestions as to what applications I should build that would be appealing to employers? Also I should note that I think of myself as quite proficient in working with GIT and Github, does that net me any additional points when applying myself?

Comment: @SebastienDErrico As I've stated in the question, finding a job locally would prove to be quite difficult due to a strong language barrier. I know learning the language would increase my odds but I don't feel sufficiently motivated to do so and will only go that route once all other options have been exhausted.

Comment: Former _Ausbilder_ for FIAE here. Most established German companies will not give you a chance without some form of formal training. Getting into one of these, your best bet is to get an _Ausbildungsplatz_ for Fachinformatik. If you have Abitur, tell them you want to do a fast-track 2 year version where you skip year one in _Berufschule_. Put this into your cover letter. The new Azubi season starts in August or September (depending on state). Most companies will love you if you have demonstrable coding skills, but might not be Java. I would consider you for a trainee role, but I'm in the UK.

Comment: @Matthew Develop something that interests you. You're more likely to stick with the project and make it good. Prospects don't really care what you've done as long as it's something that works. The product itself doesn't matter, it's the fact that you made it that matters.

Comment: ... if you want to talk more, in German, find a way to contact me and I'm happy to give you some more specific advice.

Comment: @simbabque Thank you for your comments and the opportunity to continue this discussion. According to your profile info you can be found on *irc.perl.org in #perl and #perlde*. I can hop in there now and we can exchange contacts. If not let me know any other way I can come in contact with you.

Comment: As @Jonast92 said, prospects don't really care about the topic, usually, the hiring technical guy will check for the architecture, design patterns, good practices, etc. used in your project

Comment: @SebastienDErrico In my experience they don't even ask to see the code. Probably sometimes, but I haven't had to.

Comment: @Matthew - Well, I personally just googled it, including how to conduct yourself in interviews. It's a negotiation, sell yourself as well as possible, so don't say things which harm your position unnecessarily. Are you sure you have no experience? Think about everything you have programmed. Your first paragraph already sounds quite good. Being able to handle version control is a plus. The main questions are: Can you start to make a program and finish it? And can you get into existing code and work on it? And most importantly: Can you figure out solutions to problems on your own (Google/SE)?

Comment: "but for now it's just game related stuff that wouldn't be interesting to any serious employer" - I've heard mixed advice on this, but from personal experience, if it's solid from a technical POV, game code isn't worthless for a portfolio. For example, I got an offer from a big defense contractor because they liked my vehicular combat sim.

Comment: @Matthew - Also, employers will know that you lack actual "real" experience. So your best way to sell yourself is to demand a lower wage than normal (not too low of course). Being aware of your position and having proper self-evaluation is an important indicator as well. And don't focus too much on the job requirements - they are not all obligatory. Remember, there is no big supply of programmers out there, you are not competing with 50-100 others on each job offer. Look out for small/moderate sized businesses, they tend to be more lenient in regards to CVs - yet more demanding of true skills.

Comment: @Matthew Sure, go on. IRC is fine.

Comment: @Battle When I said I have no experience it was in the context of looking for a job. I would say that the answer to all 3 of your questions is a firm yes, however I am still looking for an idea about which kind of programs I should develop that would impress the employers the most and thus giving me the biggest advantage of landing a job.

Comment: @Matthew - Well, 3x firm yes is a great start. The question is how much time is available to you to develop it. But you can't be expected to pull out a great idea out of nowhere in order to impress them. The thing which is supposed to impress them is *how* you code and everything revolving around it (sense for proper UI design for example, version control, how to integrate code, how to structure it well, etc). I'd simply suggest you try to apply right now, while in the meantime you work on that program. But keep that project small, you'll want to finish it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Matthew - Small hint: I created a text splitter, to be able to automatically split text up into 1000 character chunks, taking regard for word and paragraph coherence, along with the @ name references and post enumeration for 9gag in C#. That's a small project. Maybe aim for that size or slightly bigger, but round it up to look shiny (UI- and user control wise).

Comment: @Battle Hm might be a good idea to take some of the questions I answer on StackOverflow and build an application that implements and connects them together in some fancy fashion. I understand the point about keeping it small and actually finishing it. I have plenty of time on my hands though, so that's not an issue.

Comment: @Battle Also, is my StackOverflow profile of any relevance when it comes to my portfolio or presentation? I was thinking it could be useful to show in addition to my Github profile to demonstrate that I am active in the community and am quick to find solutions to code based problems.

Comment: @Matthew - I heard that sometimes it's a good idea to reference your StackOverflow profile, but I have to admit I know too little about that. After all, points mean that somebody thought you made a good question or answer. However the magnitude of activity on SO and your activities on other SE sites are also displayed, which can be an indicator to wasting time. But knowing your way around SO, being able to seek information you need and being able to write properly is positive as well. It's a double edged sword with a general tendency to be rather positive in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Employer will want you to give them proof of proficiency. For someone out of school it is typically a diploma. When advancing in career it'll be work experience and actions done.

In your situation you'll have to choose where to invest you time to get such proof of proficiency.

You mostly nailed formal degrees and certificates. Contributing to open source software and having proof (commit on your name) can also be good to show. Setting up a public repository with simple project demonstrating your coding skills can also give you visibility.

If you have time and mean, the easiest way would probably be to get a formal degree as it is the most "classic" way to go. The other ways are mostly dependent of company process and requirement where not having a diploma can have HR drop your CV, however in the absence of a diploma any contribution or side project is an advantage against other candidates.

About the language aspect. In Europe you can land a job in some companies even not speaking the local language well on the conditions on being proficient in English and probably willing to learn the local language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, too bad the question has been placed on hold. Don't know if it will be around for much longer. Anyhow would contributions to large open-source projects be of interest to employers, also what kind of side projects would be most beneficial to do?

Comment: Yes, if the employer is aware of open source, that is relevant. Include links to your github or whatever social coding thing you use in your CV. If you apply in Germany, mention it in your cover letter. Other countries might vary.